# Subobject classifier in $Set^{C^{op}}$

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I'm reading *"Sheaves in geometry and logic"* and I'm not sure if i'm understanding some definitions.

> We have our functor $\Omega$ defined on objects by $\Omega(C)$$=\{$$S|$ $S$ is a sieve on C in $\mathcal{C}$ $\}$ and on arrows $g: C^{'} \rightarrow C$ by
>
> $\Omega(f)$: $S \rightarrow S·g$
>
> such that $S·g=$$\{$$h|$ $g\circ h$$\in S$$\}$
>
> We define $true: 1\rightarrow \Omega$ sending each $C \in \mathcal{C}$ to the maximal sieve on $C \in \Omega(C)$
>
> Then if $Q$ is a subfunctor of $P$ we've got the map $\phi_c (x)$$=$$\{$$f|$$ $$x·f\in Q(dom(f)) \}$ where $f$ ranges over all morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ with codomain C

I don't  get what $x·f$ does mean since $P$ doesn't have to be a representable functor so x is not really a function which can be composed.

Comment: Since presheaves are contravariant functors, it is not unusual to write the action of morphisms on the right.

Comment: So.. $f:A \rightarrow C$ $ $ $f\in \phi_c (x)$ $\iff$ $Pf(x) \in Q(A)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: thanks a lot i was unfamiliar with the notation now every makes perfect sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalizing the examples of groups acting on a set or rings acting on abelian groups, we can consider categories acting on sets. The simplest description is that any functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Set}$ gives a left action of $\mathcal{C}$, and $G : \mathcal{C}^\circ \to \mathrm{Set}$ gives a right action.

And following the examples, in the case of a right action we would notation $x \cdot f$ to denote the result of applying the function $G(f)$ to the element $x$.